# How would I fix the attribute error "'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'. Did you mean: 'decode'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone please help with errors in this script? 1 error that I keep getting is "'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'. Did you mean: 'decode'". I don't know how to fix that in the script.

```
z = (priv.to_string().encode('hex'))
url = ("https://etherscan.io/address/%s"%address)

html = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("div", {"class": "col-md-6"})
value = table.findAll('td')[1].text.split(' ')[0].strip()


dosya3 = open("eth-adresler.txt", "a")
dosya3.write(str(i)+" "+"PRV Key = "+z+"  ADR = 0x"+address+" "+str(value) + "\n")
time.sleep(0.2)


tp = 1+float(value)
if tp > 1:
    print("--------------------")
    print("-----BULUNDU--------")
    print("Private Key     = "+z)
    print("Adres           = 0x"+address)
    print("Ether Miktar    = "+str(value))
    print("--------------------")

    dosya4=open("BULUNAN.txt","a")
    dosya4.write(z+" "+"0x"+address+" "+str(value)+ "\n")
    dosya4.close()
else:
    print (str(i) + " " + "private key = " + z + " " + "Adress = 0x" + address + "  " + str(value))

i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have borrowed that code from a Python 2 sample.  The `.encode('hex')` thing is simply not available in Python 3.

You should use:

```
import binascii
...
z = binascii.b2a_hex( priv.to_string() ).decode('ascii')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to upvote but I don't have enough points.

Comment: You should be able to "accept" the answer, however.